# RSS feed for gas prices and how to interpret the feed

Tags: rss

I am trying to add a RSS feed of gas prices based on location to my application.

I googled for RSS feed for gas prices and bumped onto Motortrend's gas price feed

http://www.motortrend.com/widgetrss/gas-

The feed seems to be fine, but the price value seem to be depicted in alphabets as below

`Chevron   3921 Irvine Blvd, Irvine, CA 92602     (0.0 miles)
Monday, May 10, 2010 9:16 AM
Regular: ZEIECHK    Plus: ZEHGIHC   Premium: ZEGJEGE    Diesel: N/A`

How do I interpret these value to come up with a value for the gas price? Or is it internal to Motortrend's and cannot be used elsewhere?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View the source of [Vista Motortrend Sidebar](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/files/folders/89553/download.aspx) by downloading file, renaming file extension to .zip. Then unzip source and look at /js/gas.js file. You will find a js function called parsePrice(). It is basically a character conversion to find the Unicode value, and some simple math.